# Unordered list won't move beneath my image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to have an unordered list below my home-linked image for the navigation of a website. For some reason, I cannot figure out how to make this work!

```css
.logo {
  width: 50vmin;
}

.logo-container {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2.5vmin;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 27px;
  float: left;
}

.navbar-item {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<a href="home" class="logo-container">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Logotest123.jpg" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </a>
    <br>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
    </ul>
```

When I try to run this code the ul is displayed to the right of the image, not below where I want it. Any solutions?

Comment: Remove `float: left;` from `.logo-container` and/or `.navbar`.

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/P120PKX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the `float` or use `clear: both`.

Without `float` -

```css
.logo {
  width: 50vmin;
}

.logo-container {
  margin-left: 2.5vmin;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.navbar-item {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
 
<a href="home" class="logo-container">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Logotest123.jpg" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </a>
    <br>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
    </ul>
```

With `float` and `clear` -

```css
.logo {
  width: 50vmin;
}

.logo-container {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2.5vmin;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 27px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar-item {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<a href="home" class="logo-container">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Logotest123.jpg" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    </a>
    <br>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="navbar-item">item</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I recommend you to not use `float` unless there is a specific need for using it.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the float property in .logo-container and .navbar.
Use CSS codes as follows:

```
.logo {
  width: 50vmin;
}

.logo-container {
  margin-left: 2.5vmin;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.navbar-item {
  color: #e1e1e1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your image to position absolute, and then add margin-top to move it down a bit:

Here is a code pen, https://codepen.io/mikejact/pen/xxOWmGY

And the changed code:

```
.logo-container {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2.5vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  
}
```